# Variable assignment to getElementById, not working

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

I've tried looking on stackoverflow, but can't quite find the same issue as me - I'm certain the issue is easy to solve, but somehow...it's not working.

I have some inputs, which will add/multiply/subtract/divide etc, in a calculator format.
What I want, is to remove unnecessary references to `getElementById` by declaring the variables outside of my function block (I don't want any fancy multiple-getElementById assignments).

My Javascript is below:

```
//Declarations: designed to minimze calls to document.getElementByID
    var number1 = document.getElementById("num1");
    var number2 = document.getElementById("num2");
    var numAnswer = document.getElementById("answer");

    //Add together two numbers
    function add()
    {
        numAnswer.value = parseFloat(number1.value) + parseFloat(number2.value);
    }
```

It's driving me insane - if I take out the variables and just use plain old `document.getElementById`, everything works.  This should be so easy, but it's just not working.  I've checked spelling, and it all seems okay - is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Pretty sure it's all about scopes.

Comment: I needed the variables to be globals, as I have other functions they have to be used in...my little javascript book at home assures me this should work. And MDN said it should too. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work provided the script you show in your question appears *after* the elements in your page source. Otherwise the browser hasn't parsed those elements yet so it can't find them by ID.

The other way to get it to work is to do the assignments in an `onload` or document-ready handler, because by the time `onload` or document-ready occurs *all* elements are accessible no matter where they are in the page source.

Comment: Wait...After...?  This script is in the header - I thought that didn't matter?

Comment: you'll want to do DOM manipulation only after the DOM has been loaded - i.e. window.onload = function() { ... stuff ... };

Comment: @kinakuta, if I use `window.onload`, doesn't that require a function? And if I declare variables inside a function, then they are only local, right?  Is there a way to force a javascript `<script>` in it's entirety to run when the window loads?

Comment: Simplest way forward is to move all script blocks to the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag

Comment: @user-Unknown yes, it requires a function that gets called with the onload event - this is event-driven programming and it's the bulk of DOM manipulation. Just put everything you need to do inside that function because that's when you want it to run - AFTER the window has loaded.

Comment: @kinakuta, thanks I'll consider that later...but for now I'm forced to work with what I've got.  Thanks again guys!

Comment: @user-Unknown: As Phil says, the easiest option is to just move your existing script to the bottom of the page. If you want to use `onload` instead, you still declare your variables as globals outside your onload handler, but you set the variables using `document.getElementById()` within the `onload` handler function. Then your `add()` and other functions will work fine _assuming you know they won't ever be called before_ `onload`...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine as you've included it in your question.  You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kXrDF/.

What that means is that there is something else wrong that you have not included in your question.  Perhaps you can include more of your code so we can help you find what else might be causing it.

To test the scope of your "global" variables, you can set a break point in the add() function and check the values of number1, number2 and numAnswer.  If you haven't yet figured out how to set a breakpoint and inspect variables, I'd highly recommend doing so.  If you still can't, then you can put temporary tests into your add() code like this to narrow down what the issue is:

```
if (!number1) alert("number1 is not valid");
if (!number2) alert("number2 is not valid");
if (!numAnswer) alert("numAnswer is not valid");
```

The other possibility is that your code is running too early before the page has been loaded in which case the initial code can't find the DOM elements because they don't exist yet.  To prevent that from being an issue, you need to make sure your code doesn't run until after the page has loaded.  You can do that by placing your code after the page elements or by using one of the various techniques for detecting when the page has loaded and not running your code that initialized your global variables until then.  The frameworks like jQuery and YUI all have built in functions for helping you run code after the page has been loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I fixed it by moving the `<script>` down the page...I did try those `!number1` alerts and everythign was OK.  I'll check out breakpoints for future use! :D

Comment: @user-Unknown - FYI, as I see you're fairly new here, it would be nice if you gave yourself a meaningful user name so if we cross paths again in the future, we might have a chance at recognizing each other.